# Input type checkbox in php not same in html

Tags: php, html, input, checkbox, echo

If i want to disable a checkbox with html i need to insert it in input tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="someone" name="any"  disabled> html
```

But if i want to build it with PHP and disable depends on a condition i will write:

```
$question = 'foo';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="someone" name="any"';
                if ($question == 'foo'){
                    echo 'disabled';
                }
                echo '">php';
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" class="someone" name="any"  disabled> html';
```

If you try you will see form google devtools that are write at same way but only html works

[image]

Why????

Comment: the two pieces of code are not the same - look at the extra `"` at the end after `disabled`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the above PHP is that you incorrectly have an extra closing quote - if you were to use `printf` you needn't have complicated/confusing syntax like this.

Consider:

```
printf(
    '<input type="checkbox" class="someone" name="any" value="1" %s />', 
    ( $question=='foo' ? 'disabled' : '' )
);
```

The `%s` is a placeholder which is substituted by the value from the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because both inputs have the same name attribute. Each checkbox is a unique input element, and generally each have their own distinct value for the name attribute. I'm not entirely sure, but having two inputs with the same name might cause unpredictable behavior in browsers.

Just as a heads up, you can also simplify the way you write that code, as well, by using a string variable inline, like so:

```
$question = 'foo';
$disabled = $question ? 'disabled' : ''
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="someone" name="any" '.$disabled.'>';
```

Even better, it's best practice to separate your HTML from your PHP for example like so:

```
<?php
    $question = 'foo';
    $disabled = $question ? 'disabled' : '';
?>

<input type="checkbox" class="someone" name="any" <?php echo $disabled; ?>>
```